# Set the length of input text as per the language choosen for input in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input, thymeleaf

I have a div where there is an input given to user. I have to apply a validation that restrict the user to input 50 words if the input is in English else if it is in "Japanese" then it should allow only 35 words only. So I have to set the validation for these two inputs. Currently restriction is there and it restricts on the basis of Settings of website i.e if website settings is on for English then it will allow 50 words only regardless of what would be the input in "English" or "Japanese". So I want restriction on input rather than is should be based on website settings

Here I want to add some JS code on click event or something like that to make the th:maxlength dynamic so that length can be restrict on the basis of input in "alertmessage" field

```js
$('#alertMessage').on("click", function(e) {

  $("#sendMessageDuringThunder").addClass("text-white");
  $('#alertMessage').addClass('highlight-input-message');
  $('#alertMessageTable').fadeIn().css('display', 'inline-block');
  $('.notification-div').removeClass('rounded-bottom');
  $('.noti-alert-dismissible').removeClass('rounded-bottom rounded-right');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-inline-class" th:if="${notification.notification=='thunder-alert'}">
  <th:block th:with="maxLength=${session.usercontext.getDefaultLanguage()=='en'?50:35}">
    <div th:classappend="${notification.currentStatus}?visible:hide" id="alertMessageBlock">
      <input id="alert-issued-on" type="hidden" th:attr="issuedOn=${notification.generatedOn}" />
      <input id="alertMessage" autocomplete="off" class="d-down-none input-message" th:maxlength="${maxLength}" name="alertMessage" type="text" th:placeholder="#{label.write.message}" />
      <i id="sendMsgIP" class="fas fa-spinner fa-lg fa-spin cursor hidden d-down-none px-1"></i>
      <i class="fas fa-chevron-circle-right cursor notification-alert-heading-grey d-down-none px-1 fa-lg" id="sendMessageDuringThunder"></i>
    </div>
  </th:block>
</div>
```

Comment: "Here's the HTML code" - you haven't posted the code in question, please add it.

Comment: I've never heard anyone count words in Japanese; usually essays etc are restricted by character count. But anyway, in either case you can't do this in HTML only - so you will have to use JavaScript to tokenise the input and provide the user with feedback.

Comment: @Shilly There are no spaces in Japanese, you'd need to use something like kuromoji or rakutenma.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(selector).attr(maxlength,value)
```

In value you can provide actual value.
For Example:

```
$("#inputID").attr(maxlength,50)
```

Comment: I want separate max length i.e for English it should be 50 and for Japanese it should  be 35

Comment: $(selector).attr(maxlength,value) before this check for particular language and add length accordingly.

if(language === 'English'){$(selector).attr(maxlength,50)} else {$(selector).attr(maxlength,100)}